# Calculating or finding info about the value of a market? for example Cloud Storage

Tags: data, statistics, market-data, market

I am assembling a pitch which will aim towards investors by the end of this year/beginning of next year, and I need to gather information such as how much the Cloud Storage market is worth and how much the Hard Drive market is worth.

How is such statistical data found?

Comment: This is not the correct forum for this question.

Comment: @LouisMarascio oh, ok. Where could I ask such a question?

Comment: I have no idea.

Comment: @LouisMarascio dang!

Comment: +1: This is not a bad question, only its off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://www.forbes.com/sites/louiscolumbus/2015/01/24/roundup-of-cloud-computing-forecasts-and-market-estimates-2015/

Does this give you a place to start?

Comment: It might, I am going to accept this as an answer because I finished with the question ´How is such statistical data found?´, and the link you provided does provide statistics.